# How to access foreign fields through a queryset through two filters?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class pair(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)

class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
```

I would like to filter by user and grab the name of their associated institution. The below filter doesn't seem to work:

```
list_of_accounts = pair.objects.filter(user = request.user.id).values(institution__name)
```

When I do this, I get "global name 'institution__name' not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_of_accounts = pair.objects.filter(user = request.user.id).values_list('institution__name', flat=True)
```

'institution__name' should be in single quotes.

or you can fetch like;

```
list_of_accounts = request.user.pair_set.all().values_list('institution__name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  The output is the following: [{'institution__name': u'Johnson'}, {'institution__name': u'Birbeck'}, {'institution__name': u'LSU'}] . How can I just have a list of the values? like [Johnson, Birbeck, LSU]

Comment: use values_list() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: I read that. But I just a tuple which makes the data structure even more complex no? [(u'Johnson',), (u'Birbeck',), (u'LSU',)]

Comment: I see. I have to use flat =True.

Comment: Exactly. you have to use flat=True